# Having a Bioconductor package as a dependency when submitting to CRAN

Tags: r, r-package, cran, bioconductor

I am using R 4.3.0() on a Windows 11 machine.

```
Error message:
E  checking package dependencies
   Package required but not available: 'bioconductorpackage'
   
   See section 'The DESCRIPTION file' in the 'Writing R Extensions'
   manual.
─  Done with R CMD check
─  Cleaning up files and user
```

Platform:   Windows Server 2022, R-devel, 64 bit

I am trying to write a package to submit to CRAN. However, one of the dependencies is a package from Bioconductor. When I run `devtools::check_rhub()`, I get the error message: `Package required but not available: 'bioconductordependency'`

This dependency is required for large portions of my package to work, so it is inappropriate to put under "Suggests" as has been recommended in some other posts.

I have tried the approach detailed [here](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/3365/r-package-development-how-does-one-automatically-install-bioconductor-packages), and still get the error. I have tried placing it under `Depends`, `Imports`, and `Suggests` to no avail.

Is there something I can set in the `DESCRIPTION` file or in the `devtools::check_rhub()` function to indicate that I want R to search for dependencies in Bioconductor as well?

`R CMD --as-cran check` runs with no problems (0 errors, 0 warnings, 0 notes)

Comment: have you tried the command line `R CMD CHECK --as-cran [name of tar.gz file]`   ?

Comment: Further, please post (by editing) your R version, your OS & version, and the exact text of the error message(s) that are displayed.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft The command line works without issue. I have added the changes as requested to the original query as well as some further details. I also updated my repositories to ensure I have bioconductor listed.

Comment: Then this sounds more like a defect in `check_rhub` .

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Thank you for your help. I will put in an issue notification with rhub.